# How can I add two images inside the print area?

Tags: java, image, printing, graphics, thermal-printer

I'm printing using a thermal printer. I can print text and it works perfectly but I'd like to append 2 images to text, one on top and one at the bottom of the text.
I'm trying using this code, it can print text perfectly but the only one image I'm trying to print doesn't show up.
Maybe I should have to add it inside g2d variable?
And if this is the problem, How could I do it without deleting my text?

```
class ReceiptPrint implements Printable {

    SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat();
    String receiptDetailLine;
    public static final String pspace = "               ";//15-spaces

    public int print(Graphics graphics, PageFormat pageFormat, int pageIndex)
            throws PrinterException {

        df.applyPattern("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
        String strText = null;
        final String LF = "\n";// text string to output
        int lineStart;           // start index of line in textarea
        int lineEnd;             // end index of line in textarea
        int lineNumber;
        int lineCount;
        final String SPACE = "          ";//10 spaces
        final String SPACES = "         ";//9
        final String uline = "________________________________________";
        final String dline = "----------------------------------------";
        String greetings = "GRAZIE PER L'ACQUISTO";
        receiptDetailLine = "asdasdasda";

        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) graphics;
        Font font = new Font("MONOSPACED", Font.BOLD, 9);

        if (pageIndex < 0 || pageIndex >= 1) {
            return Printable.NO_SUCH_PAGE;
        }
        JTextArea textarea = new JTextArea(10, 40);

        textarea.append(SPACES + "sadasdsad" + "\n");

        textarea.append(" " + SPACES + "sadasdsad" + "\n");

        textarea.append(SPACES + "sadasdsad" + "\n");

        textarea.append("" + SPACES + "sadasdsad" + "\n");

        textarea.append(SPACES + "sadasdsad" + "\n");

        textarea.append(uline + "\n");
        textarea.append("Order Ref:" + "   " + receiptDetailLine + "\n");
        textarea.append(dline + "\n");
        textarea.append(" Qty     Description" + SPACES + "  Price" + LF);
        textarea.append(dline + "\n");

        System.out.println(2);

        String printedLine = "       Service Charge Complimentary";
        textarea.append(printedLine + LF);

        textarea.append(LF + SPACES + "   Your Reciept\n" + SPACE + greetings + LF);
        textarea.append(df.format(new Date()) + LF);
        textarea.setEditable(false);

        g2d.translate(pageFormat.getImageableX(), pageFormat.getImageableY());

        g2d.setFont(font);
        lineNumber = 0;
        lineCount = textarea.getLineCount();
        strText = textarea.getText();
        

        //Provo a stampare un'immagine
        MediaTracker mt = new MediaTracker(textarea);

        String imagePath = "/mydir/TempQr1.bmp";
        //--- Load the image and wait for it to load
        Image image = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(imagePath);
        mt.addImage(image, 0);


        while (lineCount != 0) {
            try {

                lineStart = textarea.getLineStartOffset(lineNumber);
                lineEnd = textarea.getLineEndOffset(lineNumber);
                strText = textarea.getText(lineStart, lineEnd - lineStart);
            } catch (Exception exception) {
                System.out.println("Printing error:" + exception);                  // have to catch BadLocationException
            }

            g2d.drawString(strText, 1, (lineNumber + 1) * 18);
            //g2d.drawIma
            //spacing    between lines
            lineNumber = lineNumber + 1;
            lineCount--;
        }
        return Printable.PAGE_EXISTS;
    }
}
```

Any suggestions on how should I do it?

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Add the components to a JPanel and print the JPanel?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @camickr I created a JPanel and added all the components to it, then I printed the JPanel using this code where comp is my JPanel:

```
public void stampaDirettamente(Component comp, boolean fill) throws PrinterException {
    Paper paper = new Paper();
    double paperWidth = 3;//3.25
    double paperHeight = 6.69;//11.69
    double leftMargin = 0.12;
    double rightMargin = 0.10;
    double topMargin = 0;
    double bottomMargin = 0.01;

    paper.setSize(paperWidth * 200, paperHeight * 200);
    paper.setImageableArea(leftMargin * 200, topMargin * 200,
            (paperWidth - leftMargin - rightMargin) * 200,
            (paperHeight - topMargin - bottomMargin) * 200);


    PrintRequestAttributeSet aset = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();
    aset.add(OrientationRequested.PORTRAIT);


    PageFormat pf = new PageFormat();
    pf.setPaper(paper);
    pf.setOrientation(PageFormat.PORTRAIT);
    

    BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(
                    (int) Math.round(pf.getWidth()),
                    (int) Math.round(pf.getHeight()),
                    BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);

    Graphics2D g2d = img.createGraphics();
    g2d.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    g2d.fill(new Rectangle(0, 0, img.getWidth(), img.getHeight()));
    ComponentPrinter cp = new ComponentPrinter(comp, fill);
    try {
        cp.print(g2d, pf, 0);
    } finally {
        g2d.dispose();
    }
    
    
    PrinterJob printerJob = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
    Printable printable = cp;

    pf = printerJob.validatePage(pf);
    //boolean don = printerJob.printDialog();    //Uncomment this to have a print dialog
    printerJob.setPrintable(printable, pf);    
    try {
        printerJob.print(aset);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```